# Not able to invoke remote method in RMI communication

Tags: rmi

I am trying to execute one RMI program but i am getting exception when i try to call the remote method from RMI client program.

Server program:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;


public class Hello extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface {

    private String message;

    public Hello() throws RemoteException{
           int port=1024; 
          Registry registry;
           try{
              registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
              registry.rebind("samplermi", this);
              System.out.println ("Server started and listening on port " + port);

          }
          catch(RemoteException e){
              System.out.println("remote exception"+ e);
          }
      }

      public String sayHi (String name) throws RemoteException {
          message = "Hi .. Welcome " + name;
      return message;
      }


      public static  void main(String args[]){
          try{
              Hello serverObj = new Hello();
          }
          catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.exit(1);
          }
          }


}
```

Client Program:

```
registry=LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress,serverPort);
          if(registry !=null){
               String[] availRemoteServices = registry.list();
              for(int i=0;i<availRemoteServices.length;i++){
                  System.out.println("Service " + i + ": " +availRemoteServices[i]);                  
              }           
          }
           rmiServer=(HelloInterface)(registry.lookup("samplermi"));

          System.out.println("calling remote method!");
          // call the remote method
          welcomeMsg = rmiServer.sayHi(text);
      System.out.println("Message from server: " + welcomeMsg);
```

I am getting connection exception only at the time of calling the remote method sayHI. It works fine for lookup and listing the service name.

```
R:\Deptapps\itdm\Sample_RMI>java NewSampleRMIClient
Getting Registry Object from server!!
Registry Object Created!!
Service 0: samplermi
Services listed successfully!

Look up successful!
calling remote method!

java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Hello_Stub.sayHi(Unknown Source)
        at NewSampleRMIClient.main(NewSampleRMIClient.java:42)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Note: The same program is working correctly when running server in solaris and client from windows. It is not working only when running server in AIX and client from windows.

Kindly can someone help in resolving this issue. I have been trying to fix this issue since 2 days but no use. Please help me!!

Comment: Is there any kind of network device between client and server which can cause the connection to fail?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [Item A.1 of the RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain).

Answer (score -1):

Run `rmiregistry.exe` before running `Hello.class`, it solved my problem.

Comment: It won't solve this one. His Registry lookup has obviously already succeeded. Not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

RMi Working on the default port 1099. So no need to create the port.. If you are using default port number then exception may not be fired. and program may work properly.

Comment: Incorrect. You have to supply a port number to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`. There is a default *value,* given by `Registry.REGISTRY_PORT,` but you have to supply it to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`. And this doesn't answer the question. His `lookup()` has succeeded, it is his *method call* that has failed.